# StaleElementReferenceException selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, phantomjs

I'm writing a crawler using Selenium, Python and PhantomJS to use Google's reverse image search. So far I've successfully been able to upload an image and crawl the search results on the first page. However, when I try to click on the search results navigation, I'm getting a StaleElementReferenceError. I have read about it in many posts but still I could not implement the solution. Here is the code that breaks:

```
ele7 = browser.find_element_by_id("nav")
ele5 = ele7.find_elements_by_class_name("fl")

count = 0
for elem in ele5:
    if count <= 2:
        print str(elem.get_attribute("href"))
        elem.click()
        browser.implicitly_wait(20)
        ele6 = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("rc")
        for result in ele6:
            f = result.find_elements_by_class_name("r")
            for line in f:
                link = line.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")[0].get_attribute("href")
                links.append(link)
                parsed_uri = urlparse(link)
                domains.append('{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri))
            count += 1
```

The code breaks at print `str(elem.get_attribute("href"))` . How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking a link will cause the browser to go to another page; make references to the elements in old page (`ele5`, `elem`) invalid.

Modify the code not to reference invalid elements.

For example, you can get urls before you visit other pages:

```
ele7 = browser.find_element_by_id("nav")
ele5 = ele7.find_elements_by_class_name("fl")

urls = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in ele5]  # <-----

browser.implicitly_wait(20)

for url in urls[:2]:  # <------
    print url
    browser.get(url)  # <------ used `browser.get` instead of `click`.
                      #         ; using `element.click` will cause the error.

    ele6 = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("rc")
    for result in ele6:
        f = result.find_elements_by_class_name("r")
        for line in f:
            link = line.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")[0].get_attribute("href")
            links.append(link)
            parsed_uri = urlparse(link)
            domains.append('{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri))
```